# Most efficient way to get SUM for 2 different values in same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like this:

| Color | Quarter | TotalCost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Q1 | 100 |
| Red | Q1 | 150 |
| Red | Q1 | 100 |
| Red | Q1 | 125 |
| Red | Q2 | 100 |
| Red | Q2 | 125 |
| Red | Q2 | 150 |

The goal is to get the total cost for the current quarter (Q2) and previous quarter (Q1) for the value in the Color column.

I'm currently doing this, which works:

```
SELECT      Color
,           'CurrentQuarter'  = SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q2' THEN TotalCost END)
,           'PreviousQuarter' = SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q1' THEN TotalCost END)
FROM        #test
GROUP BY    Color
```

The results need to have the totals side by side:

| Color | CurrentQuarter | PreviousQuarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 375 | 475 |

The actual table I'm using has a few hundred thousand rows, and I have to run queries like this for different things (Color, Part, City, Owner, etc)

Is there a more efficient way to write this simple query?

Comment: The query looks good. If you have performance issue with that query, try this: `with q1 as (select color, sum(totalcost) as cost from test where quarter = 'q1' group by color), q2 as (select color, sum(totalcost) as cost from test where quarter = 'q2' group by color), c as (select distinct color from test) select c.color, q1.cost, q2.cost from c left join q1 on c.color=q1.color left join q2 on c.color = q2.color;`. If query is still slow, create an index on color and see if that improves performance.

Comment: Thanks .. I'm sure my question seems silly, but I'm often comparing things in two different timeframes. Always looking for ways to improve my code!

Comment: Your question is not silly at all. The question is clear. You also mentioned how query will be different for your use case of part, city, etc. It shows you are looking for tips that improve upon your ideas. Good for you, Jeff!

Comment: Nothing really to improve other than to note column aliases shouldn't be treated as 'string literals' - so remove the single quotes.

Comment: FYI, the syntax you are using for aliasing is deprecated. Ideally, don't use literal strings for aliasing at all.

Comment: your indenting is "interesting"   most people have the comma at the end of the line and indent the code

Comment: @Hogan "most people"? I've seen plenty of commas at the start of the line - I use them because its more practical when you need to comment out various lines for testing.

Comment: @DaleK -- if the comma is at the start then everything but the first line is "easer to comment out".  If the comma is at the end then everything but the last line "easier to comment out".  In both cases the lines in total are just as hard to comment out -- it depends on if you are commenting out one in the middle or the first or last one.  Putting the comma at column 1 here ruins the advantage of indentation since it is harder to see the indentation.  Except maybe something that caught on at one location  I don't really believe you have seen a lot or the majority like this.

Comment: @Hogan Yeah but I tend to add columns I know I need first, and have the ones I am working on last. I didn't say a majority, but enough to know its not uncommon. I'd agree with the indenting as a best practice, I think were commas go is just personal preference.

Comment: @DaleK -- ruining the indenting bothers me more than the start of the line or end of the line.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the aliasing issue. Thank you. I forget exactly when I started putting the comma at the beginning, but it did have to do with commenting out lines when troubleshooting. I saw someone else's code with it, and it made sense so I started doing it too. After seeing it this way for so long, it doesn't affect the way I see the indenting.

Answer (score 1):

Your data

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   Color     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,Quarter   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,TotalCost INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO test
(Color,Quarter,TotalCost) VALUES 
('Red','Q1',100),
('Red','Q1',150),
('Red','Q1',100),
('Red','Q1',125),
('Red','Q2',100),
('Red','Q2',125),
('Red','Q2',150);
```

there exist numerous approaches to get your desired result one approach is `join` in `subquery`

```
SELECT t1.color,
       CurrentQuarter,
       PreviousQuarter
FROM
  (SELECT color,
          sum(TotalCost) CurrentQuarter
   FROM test
   WHERE QUARTER='Q2'   
   GROUP BY color) t1
JOIN
  (SELECT color,
          sum(TotalCost) PreviousQuarter
   FROM test
   WHERE QUARTER='Q1'
   GROUP BY color) t2 ON t1.color=t2.color
```

Your query requires QUARTER field

```
SELECT      Color
,           'CurrentQuarter'  = SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q2' THEN TotalCost END)
,           'PreviousQuarter' = SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q1' THEN TotalCost END)
FROM        test
GROUP BY    Color, Quarter
```

where it brings

| Color | CurrentQuarter | PreviousQuarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red |  | 475 |
| Red | 375 |  |

it requires another `Subquery`

```
SELECT Color,
            MAX(CurrentQuarter) CurrentQuarter,
            MAX(PreviousQuarter) PreviousQuarter  
            FROM
            (
SELECT      Color
,           'CurrentQuarter'  = SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q2' THEN TotalCost END)
,           'PreviousQuarter' = SUM(CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q1' THEN TotalCost END)
FROM        test
GROUP BY    Color, Quarter) T1
GROUP BY Color
```

Another approach is `Pivot`

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
SELECT      Color
,            IIF(Quarter='Q2','CurrentQuarter','PreviousQuarter') Quarter
,           SUM(TotalCost) TotalCost
FROM        test
GROUP BY    Color, Quarter
) t 
PIVOT(
    SUM(TotalCost) 
    FOR Quarter IN (
        [CurrentQuarter], 
        [PreviousQuarter])
) AS pivot_table;
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7c97c192d88493558dcf3c57096621a)

Comment: I'd expect this to be slower

Comment: This line `GROUP BY  Color, Quarter`  change it to `GROUP BY  Color` then you won't have the two row problem

Comment: Are any of these methods generally considered to be faster or more efficient than my current method of using case statements?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d3ad7af4de64b70d2a9a52938745c657

Answer (score 0):

You could use windowing functions -- depending on many things that may or may not be faster -- with the windowing function you don't need to use the group by and you can only sum elements of various windows (prior elements based on ordering, last 3 elements etc)

Here is the default case that will give you the same numbers as your prior query (but with the value for the quarter of the row on each row.)

```
  SELECT  *,
          SUM(TotalCost) OVER (PARTITION BY Quarter) AS QuarterTotalCost
  FROM        #test
```